# New Contest Idea

Tags: discussion, contest

We have already had some community building activities on the Meta, such as the themed rendering contests, marked with the [contest](/questions/tagged/contest) tag. I recently had an idea to expand on those contests. My new idea would be quite simple, and wouldn't take nearly as much time or effort as creating an entire render. It would be a simple contest, basically you would write a question, and **make it as funny as you can**, whether the question is blatantly off topic, written by someone who knows way too much or way too little about blender. Any method could be used to make the question enjoyable funny to other users. ***THE QUESTIONS SHOULD NEVER BE POSTED ON THE MAIN SITE OR IN ANY PLACE OTHER THAN THE DEDICATED CONTEST POST UNLESS THEY ARE REAL, SERIOUS QUESTIONS.*** (that is to avoid heavy resistance by the M.O.D-Team)

Instead, you would take a screenshot of your question and post it in the contest post, or you could simply copy the markdown form the "ask a question" page and paste it into the "add an answer" page on the contest post.

Winners would be picked by whoever has the most up Votes within a week, (Or any other reasonable time span)

In case your wondering what gave me this idea, it was this [highly off-topic question that Gandalf3 was able to find and save](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/8888?m=22040237#22040237)

If this idea gets enough support from the community, I'd be happy to create the contest post. **DO NOT** post funny responses here - We need community approval first

*To the M.O.D.-Team, it* ***would not*** *just be a post to collect spam.*

Comment: how bout whoever gets most DV's?

Comment: It could either be whoever gets the most Dvs also gets a prize for the worst one, or DVs are simply not counted (just like in the other contests)

Comment: it would be more accurate if you're trying to write a bad question..,. jus sayiin'

Comment: I personally like the idea of lower score wins, and if your post sounds like a real question it gets upvoted, but the more spammy, hilarious or off-topic your question is the more DVs you get- it would be more realistic indeed, but other users might not want a lot of heavily down voted answers on their meta account. Also, if it was most down votes wins, the lowest score you could ever get is 10, (I think that posts with a score of less than 10 automatically get deleted) - that might be wrong though.

Comment: It would probably be simplest to just do it by UV's. If you like the question, and this it's funny, then you upvote, if you hate the question, you downvote. If it's okay, you leave it be.

Comment: Why not reward the winner with something like 20 rep? Nothing huge, but nothing extremely small either.

Comment: @TARDISMaker I would not mind rewarding users with rep, but there is no system in place to do this (aside form upvoting two of their answers).

Comment: I don't think votes change rep in meta, I think that's only in the actual site.

Comment: exactly, which is why getting Upvoted/Downvoted on your entries would not effect your rep, and then only way to reward them with the current rep system is someone upvoting their posts on the main site, which could be called voter fraud, so for now we'd have to settle for no direct reward.

Comment: If it's not broken, I would try beating it back into shape with a hammer.

Comment: would you try to forge the blade or the spoon back into shape with your lightning shooting ban hammer?

Comment: @iKlsR I mean't not broken off entirely, should have been more specific....